# are there any ways to add ValueError for each input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, valueerror, except

So im trying to write a code where you enter the width and height of a rectangle and it gives you the area and perimeter, now obviously the inputs can only be numbers, so i want to be able to ask for another input if the current input is not a number. (tell the user to only enter numbers) .The problem is that if the first input( width) is a number and  only the second input (height) is not a number, i dont want the program to ask the user  to enter the width again, i only want the user to enter the height again not the width, since the width was already entered as a number . How do i do this?

```
while True:
try:
    a = float(input("Please enter width :"))
    b = float(input("Please enter height :"))

except ValueError:
    print("PLease only enter numbers ")
    continue

area = float(a*b)
perimeter = float((a+b)*2)

print('The area of the rectangle is {} and the perimeter of the rectangle is {} '.format(area, perimeter))
```

Answer (score 2):

The basic answer is to wrap each call to `float` in a separate `try` and handle them separately. Literally writing out two `try`s would be messy and bulky though.

Instead, I'd move that `try` into its own function then call that function twice:

```
# Let this function handle the bad-input looping 
def ask_for_float(message):
    while True:
        try:
            return float(input(message)) 

        except ValueError:
            print("Please only enter numbers ")

a = ask_for_float("Please enter width :")
b = ask_for_float("Please enter height :")
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your input in separate try blocks then you can catch the errors separately. 
For example,

```
try:
a = float(input("Please enter width :"))

except ValueError:
    print("PLease only enter numbers ")

try:
    b = float(input("Please enter height :"))

except ValueError:
    print("PLease only enter numbers ")
    continue

area = float(a*b)
perimeter = float((a+b)*2)
```